# how can bind the compiz Scale plugin to the corner of my window?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, plugins, shortcut-keys

I go to compizconfig -> scale windows -> binding and then choose "Initiate Window Picker" with the mouse icon next to it.
I check "Enabled".
Then I highlight the corners in green.

This doesn't seem to work...
  part of the problem might be that I must choose a button (there is no way to make that button choice blank).

Before I upgraded to 11.4 this was no problem but now I'm stuck.

Comment: There is a third way now: UnityTweak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose the wrong one.

Use initiate_edge instead:
[image]

Comment: @Martin McNulty lol no you're not an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to install the compiz settings manage you can edit this setting easily using gconf-editor.

The first step is to hit alt+f2 which will bring up a "run application" dialog box. In the entry field put in gconf-editor and then click 'run'. From here you will navigate to:

apps -> compiz -> plugins

You then need to find the scale plugin entries as shown below.

[image: scale gconf-editor]

In my example I am using a button, but you can fill in the 'initiate-all-edge' for scale. The edges are case sensitive.

BottomRight, TopRight, etc.